# Can't link my Paper Wallet to Blockchain

Tags: wallet

So I've created a Paper wallet using bit address.org, and have joined Blockchain.com, but can't find out how to link the two?

Also the strategy I'm using at the moment-till maybe "you" say otherwise, is-I've bought Bitcoin using Coinbase, and am trying to send money to my bitaddress.org Paper Wallet-but Coinbase isn't showing me how to do this? So I can then register the transaction-and others on the Blockchain on blockchain.com Do you think I'm using the right strategy?

Thoughts

Comment: Welcome to bitcoin.SE! Its great that you're doing research and asking questions, you'll find lots of friendly people here that are happy to help :) re: *"Do you think I'm using the right strategy?"*- no, I would consider your setup to be unnecessarily complex and insecure. As a new user, I wouldn't recommend you use a paper wallet, improper use can lead to loss. For more info see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Paper_wallet . I would also generally avoid web-wallets (like blockchain.info), take a look at https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet and choose a wallet that suits your needs well.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in your Coinbase account use their "Send" feature to send coins to your paper wallet. It will then prompt you for a wallet address to send the coins to. Enter your paper wallet address there. Choose the amount to send, etc.

More here: https://support.coinbase.com/customer/en/portal/articles/971437-how-do-i-send-digital-currency-to-another-wallet-

If you are keeping the coins for yourself, there are better alternatives than paper wallet. If you are giving as a gift, just make sure recipient knows what to do or no do with the wallet.

Comment: Thank you so much Fraggle.

I'm wondering if you'd be open to a Skype chat for some more questions? Perhaps i could send some bitcoin your way, for your time?
I could forward my questions to you first perhaps?

Thank you again.

Ernie